# How can I map a document from Firestore into a custom object and return a list of those documents in Kotlin/Jetpack Compose?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

This is what I have tried
I have a collection in Firebase named foods and I want to retreive every document and put it as a separate object in a list. Can anyone help me?

**My Food Data Class**

```
data class Food(
val name: String = "",
val weight: Double = 0.0,
val protein: Double = 0.0,
val carbohydrates: Double = 0.0,
val fat: Double = 0.0)
```

**My Repository**

```
override suspend fun getFoodData(): MutableState<List<Food>> {
    val itemList: MutableState<List<Food>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())

    fb.collection("foods")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            val items = mutableListOf<Food>()
            for (document in documents) {
                val data = document.data
                val item = Food(
                    data["food_name"] as String,
                    data["food_weight"] as Double,
                    data["food_protein"] as Double,
                    data["food_carbohydrates"] as Double,
                    data["food_fat"] as Double,
                )
                Log.d("DataFoodLog", "valueItem: $item")
                items.add(item)
            }
            itemList.value = items
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("Firestore", "Error getting documents: ", it)
        }
    Log.d("DataFoodLog","data: ${itemList.value}")
    return itemList
}
```

**This is what I have in my View Model**

```
var result = mutableStateOf<List<Food>>(emptyList())
fun getFood()
=viewModelScope.launch {
    getFoodDataResponse = Resource.Loading
    result = repo.getFoodData()
}
```

**My Firebase Structure**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please add the content of your `Food` class.

Comment: Done editing. Added what you said

Comment: What does `Log.d("DataFoodLog","data: ${itemList.value}")` print?

Comment: It prints [], I think it means an empty arrary

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).